# Entity creation windows moving each time it opens

Tags: qgis

Each time I create an feature, a window appears to customize its attributes. But with each feature I create, the window is not at the same position, and if I don't move it to the top again, it goes too far toward the bottom and "disappears". It's bothersome, because I have to move it again and again. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Try to move it where you want to have it, click OK, toggle edit mode to leave editing of the layer to save changes. Then again enter edit mode, create a new feautre (not entity, by the way, this is (Q)GIS terminology) and see if it now behaves as you want.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It didn't work unfortunately. The window that appears is still moving to the bottom of the screen little by little everytime I create a new feature. I am using QGIS 3.30.0

Comment: Closing QGIS and restart does not help, either?

Comment: No. Tried it. I tried to reset user settings too, but it's not the solution. I heard that it could be some screen resolution problem... ?

Comment: Creating a new user profile does not help? Menu Settings > User profile

Comment: Didn't work. The only way to resolve the problem by the moment is to full screen the feature creation window  that appears. But it's not convenient.